# Is Google Sign In Required everytime to upload a Video to Youtbe using JAVA..?

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a Video to my YouTube account using my own Application(Spring-boot) with the help of Google Library. But every time when I try to call the insert API of YouTube it asks for a Physical Sign in to Google Account. I want to upload my Video without Google Signin via passing the API Key or the client credentials(generated in Google Console for OAuth) in a post Request. I don't want to signin to google every time to upload a video. My account should be verified with the credentials I provide in the post Request.

```
curl --request POST
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{}'
--compressed
```

Another Question is How I can get **[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]** ..?

End Point URL : **POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos**

Google Link : [YouTube Upload Video steps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

Any Suggestion would be Very Helpful.

JAVA code snippet :

[image]

you can find this on Google Link.

Comment: Sound like you should read up on [how OAuth2 works](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2).

Comment: Your question notes java but you are posting Curl code, which are you using exactly?

Comment: And can we login to Google using username and password at code level without physical sign-in..?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to request offline access. At which point you should get a refresh token back. You can then use the refresh token to request a new access token at a later date without requiring that you login to google again.

Since your code is in Curl i have posted a response using Curl, even though your question mentons java.

```
# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Code ripped from my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

Comment: I was using the JAVA code provided by Google Library in java. added the snippet for the same. can you please suggest now in java.